# Condition to compare strings in two fields but only if one field has evaluated to true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two Textboxes:

**1.** Textbox1 gets an email address (email textbox on a form)

**2.** Textbox two asks the user to confirm email

I need to compare the email address entered in Textboxes 1 by asking the user to re-enter in textbox 2. Then evaluate a statement and set a bool to true or false.

I read on all the Methods line ***String.Equals*** and others and tried using them.

I have these two variables in a class that I need to access in other parts on the program:

```
    public static bool IsValidEmail { get; set; }
    public static bool IsValidEmailConfirmed { get; set; }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(checkEmail))
        {
            IsValidEmail = Regex.IsMatch(checkEmail, MatchEmailPattern);
        }
        else
        {
            IsValidEmail = false;
        }

        //VERIFY EMAIL ADDRESS MATCHES
        //---------------------------
        if (IsValidEmail == true)
        {
            IsValidEmailConfirmed = checkEmailConfirm.Equals(checkEmail);
        }
        else
        {
            IsValidEmailConfirmed = false;
        }
```

The problem is I only want the confirm Textbox to request an entry if the initial Textbox pass validation. It would not make sense asking some to confirm a bad email address (format). So the user enters an email, if it fails, a confirmation is not requested, however this variable  `IsValidEmail = false;` will evaluate to false which will indicate an error.

Finally if the first box pass validation and the confirmation fails, the error message ask for confirmation.

The code above is broken down as I have been trying to do different things.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't specify if it's web forms or MVC, as MVC has a really powerful helpers for this, I'm going to assume that this is web forms.

from your code, you should refactor to:

```
IsValidEmail = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(checkEmail) && Regex.IsMatch(checkEmail, MatchEmailPattern);

//VERIFY EMAIL ADDRESS MATCHES
IsValidEmailConfirmed = IsValidEmail && checkEmailConfirm == checkEmail;
```

apart of that, I would also suggest to use [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) (assuming that you use jQuery already) and do this in the client as well.

```html
<form ...>
    Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="required email" />
    Confirm email: <input type="text" id="email2" name="email2" class="required email" equalTo="#email" />
</form>
```

**Live demo** for jQuery Validate with equality among 2 fields: http://jsbin.com/imiten/1/

Comment: Yes: I am using JQuery but this is the last defense, if the user turned off JQuery, this code will never kick in, unless Client-side validation/JavaScript is turned off. Sorry I forgot to add, this is for ASP forms. Thank you my friend.

I know the JS is a demo but both field are asking for input on click. What I am trying to do is only ask for confirmation if the first entry is valid. But that's JS and I am asking ASP. I'll get to that in the coming weeks. Thanks again!

Comment: I still don't really know what do you need then :/

Answer (score 1):

You could to nest the logic or change it from a property to a function.

Nest

```
if(validEmail)
{
    if(!match)
    {
        'Code for non matching, flags/vars.
    }
    else
    {
        'Here is the point where all the data is validated.
    }
}
else
{
    'Code for invalid email, flags, variables
}
```

Or function

```
Public void validateEmail()
{
     if(!validEmail)
     {
        'Set property
        return; 'This will exit the function right here.
     }
     if(!matching)
     {
        'Set properties/vars
        return; 'Another exit.
     }

     'If the code makes it here your data is valid
}
```